# Create a View with more Partial View and different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'd like to have a view for use with the Tab jQuery that allow me to populate multiple tables (with the partial view). Basically I would like to be able to populate the tables of a database with a single view.

My model example:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

my controller:

```
public class tabController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult tab()
    {
        var tvm = new MyDbContext();
        return View(tvm);
    }
}
```

and my view:

```
@model ??????????

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
   </script>
}

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tag</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">city</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">country</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">more more</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("_tag", ????? )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("_city", Model?)

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("_country", @Model.Country)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("_note"@*, @Model.NoteShares*@)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I see the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'myprojMVC5.Models.tabs', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[myprojMVC5.Models.tabsl]

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'myprojMVC5.Models.tabs', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[myprojMVC5.Models.tabsl]'. In any case I do not know how to do, considering that in view I can only feed one model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: View model**

Create a view model containing properties for the collections you want to display

```
public class TabsVM
{
  public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller, initialize an instance of the view model and populate te collections

```
public class tabController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult tab()
  {
    var tvm = new MyDbContext();
    TabsVM model = new TabsVM()
    {
      Tabs = tvm .Tabs(),
      Cities = tvm.Citys()
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.TabsVM
....
@Html.Partial("_tag", Model.Tags)
....
@Html.Partial("_tag", Model.Cities)
```

**Option 2: Call child action only methods that return partial views**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult FetchTags()
{
  var tvm = new MyDbContext();
  var model = tvm.Tags();
  return PartialView("_tags", model);
}
```

and in the view (no model required to be passed to the view)

```
....
@Html.Action("FetchTags") // assumes the methods will be in the same controller
....
@Html.Action("FetchCities") // or you can use @{ Html.RenderAction("FetchCities"); }
```